# In spring integration, how do I catching different exceptions?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, spring-integration

In spring integration I have a simple tcp client pipe: a gateway, a tcp outbound gateway a service activator plus an error channel. In the tcp-connection-factory there is a simple interceptor. The error channel very simple, I implemented the tcp-connection-event-inbound-channel-adapter with this filter:

- org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpConnectionExceptionEvent.

So my error handler very simple,looks like this :

```
public class TcpErrorHandler {
    public void onException(){
        System.out.println("Exception!!! ");
    } 
}
```

It works, because when I have a Socket close Exception ( the server side I close the connection ) , the application writes "Exception!!!" to the console, but other hand, it doesn't work, when I have connection time out exception.
My questions are : How do I get all most relevant exceptions for me:

- Runtime Socket close Exception
- Connection time out exception
- Other exceptions

Are there any catching mechanism ?

Here is a snipet from my bean config:

```
<!-- Client side -->

<int:gateway id="gw"
    service-interface="hu.gmxdev.climaxreplica.service.SimpleGateway"
    default-request-channel="outputchannel" />

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
    type="client" host="localhost" port="10001" single-use="true"
    so-timeout="2000" deserializer="climaxDeserializer"
    interceptor-factory-chain="customInterceptorFactoryChain"/>

<int:channel id="outputchannel" />

<int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outGateway"
    request-channel="outputchannel" reply-channel="replychannel"
    connection-factory="client" request-timeout="2000" reply-timeout="2000" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="replychannel"
    method="reply" ref="echoService" id="serviceactivator">
</int:service-activator>

<int:channel id="replychannel"></int:channel>

<bean id="customInterceptorFactoryChain"
        class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpConnectionInterceptorFactoryChain">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <array>
                <bean class="hu.gmxdev.climaxreplica.service.CustomInterceptorFactory"/>
            </array>
        </property>
</bean>

<!-- Error channel -->

<int-ip:tcp-connection-event-inbound-channel-adapter id="event"
    error-channel="errorChannel"
    event-types="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpConnectionExceptionEvent" />

<int:channel id="errorChannel"></int:channel>

<int:service-activator ref="tcpErrorHandler" method="onException"
    input-channel="errorChannel">
</int:service-activator>
```

And here is my error handler :

```
public class TcpErrorHandler {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    public void onException(TcpConnectionExceptionEvent event){
        MainService mainService = appContext.getBean(MainService.class);
        mainService.setSuccess(3);
        System.out.println("Exception!!! ");
        System.out.println(event.getCause().getMessage());
    }
}
```

The interceptor is here :

```
public class CustomInterceptor extends TcpConnectionInterceptorSupport{

    public CustomInterceptor () {
        System.out.println("catched_constructor1");
    }

    public CustomInterceptor (ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
        super(applicationEventPublisher);
        System.out.println("catched_constructor");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMessage(Message<?> message) {
        System.out.println("catched_message");
        return super.onMessage(message);
    }


    @Override
    public void send(Message<?> message){
        System.out.println("catched_send");
        MessageHeaders mh = message.getHeaders();
        try {
            super.send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("catched_send_exception");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        String id = getConnectionId();
        System.out.println("catched_closed" + id);
        super.close();
    }

}
```

And my "caller" :

```
success = gateway.send("fooooooo");
```

Comment: Refer
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_exception_handling_example.htm link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `<tcp-connection-event-inbound-channel-adapter>` send to the `channel` a `Message` with `TcpConnectionExceptionEvent` (in your case) as `payload`.

Therefore your subscriber (your `TcpErrorHandler`) can accepts `TcpConnectionExceptionEvent` as a method argument.

In that method you can do further logic, e.g. extract the original `Exception` from that `IntegrationEvent`.

There are several places in the `IP` module when `TcpConnectionSupport.publishConnectionExceptionEvent` is used.

If you say that you don't catch `time out exception`, it will great if you share the logs on the matter. I wonder which place we don't `try...catch` on the `SocketTimeoutException`...

**UPDATE**

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-event-inbound-channel-adapter channel="events" 
    event-types="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpConnectionExceptionEvent"/>

<service-activator input-channel="events" ref="tcpErrorHandler"/>
```

---

```
public class TcpErrorHandler {

   public void onException(TcpConnectionExceptionEvent event) {
       System.out.println("Exception!!! ");
       event.getCause();
       ....
   } 

}
```

This should work.

**UPDATE2**

According to your code:

```
try {
   super.send(message);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("catched_send_exception");
}
```

Don't you think that it is bad to suffocate an Exception there?

From other side: would you mind switching on `DEBUG` logging level for the `org.springframework.integration` category and share here the logs, when you are sure that your `tcpErrorHandler` should be invoked?

From other side try `<int-ip:tcp-connection-event-inbound-channel-adapter>` without `event-types` at all. I mean let's see, if it handle any `IpIntegrationEvent`.

Comment: Hello Bilan ! Did you think this way ? public class TcpErrorHandler { 
 public void onException(TcpConnectionExceptionEvent event){
  System.out.println("Exception!!! ");
  System.out.println("Message:" + event.getCause().getMessage());
 }
} How do I inject TcpConnectionExceptionEvent ??? Annotaion? How?

Comment: Yes, it is. You don't need to take care about `injection`. It is a Framework responsibility. And we call it `POJO method invocation`. If you inject your `TcpErrorHandler` to a `<service-activator>` fro the `channel` from that `<tcp-connection-event-inbound-channel-adapter>`, everything will be OK.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand it. Could you post me a very short and simple, but workable example ? ( Sorry , but I have just started to work with Spring Integration... )

Comment: Added a sample to the answer

Comment: As you can see my first comment above, I have tried this, but it doesn't work at all. If I add the TcpConnectionExceptionEvent argument to my method -as you wrote - the method never will invoke, my method never Sysout "Exception!" to the console !

Comment: A added my beans and classes to original question

Comment: I have found a mistake in my int-ip:tcp-connection-event-inbound-channel-adapter. I used the error-channel instead of input channel. I corrected this, and after I able to catch more exception - as you mentioned above -, but I can't catch the timeout exception if there are no connection between client and server, for example the server doesn't listen the port. I will try your suggestion, and switch on the debug.

Comment: Thats' great! Well. I'd say that it is a separete SO question. We fixed here your issue with `event listener`. Let's accept the answer and start a new thread with link to this one.

Comment: OK, I appreciate your help !

Answer (score 1):

You can define an error channel, that you provide to your inbound adapter. Here is an example:

```
    <int:channel id="error-channel"></int:channel>
    <int-ws:inbound-gateway id="gateway" error-channel="error-channel"
    request-channel="in"  marshaller="marshaller" unmarshaller="marshaller"
    reply-channel="out" />
```

Now all exception that are thrown downstream will be catched by this error-channel.
You can then define a service activator with this error channel as an input:

```
 <int:service-activator  input-channel="error-channel"
        ref="exceptionHandler" method="handleError" output-channel="outError"></int:service-activator>
```

And this activator refers to a bean that defines error handling logic.